# Writing C program to create a 1 MB file on Linux and getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linux, stdio

I'm trying to write a simple C program for Linux that will generate a 1 MB file but I can't get this code to work. When I try to run it I get a seg fault error message thrown and I'm not really sure where it's going wrong. I do have a hunch that it is with fseek though:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[0], "w");
    fseek(fp, 1000000 - 1, SEEK_SET);
    fputc('\0', fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As already noted, you probably need to use `argv[1]` rather than `argv[0]`, but you also need to check that the argument was provided (`if (argc == 2)`), and you need to check that you successfully opened the file before writing to it (`if (fp != 0)`).  On the whole, you should also close the file after opening it.  It will actually work without `fclose(fp);` before the `return` statement, but it is better style to close what you open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`argv[0]` is the name of your binary.  You want to use `argv[1]` as your filename.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I suppose I need to read up more on command line arguments (and file IO). Thank you for the quick answer, it works now! Will accept your answer after the timer. :)